# Spring Data JPA (MySQL) saves String in exponential form rather than as a number

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I save phone number in Database using Spring Data JPA ,

In model I define this
`private String directPhone;`

while saving `supplier.directPhone="99250397679"`

And In DB it save in exponential Form

It save in this form `direct_phone: 9.925039767E9`

```
Supplier supplier=supplierRepository.findOne(new Long(1));
```

And while receiving it give me in exponential Form .

But I want in String form . Help me to get in String form. Same thing happen with `year=2005` and it save `year=2005.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't have anything to do with Spring Data. You'd bumped into this issue with plain JDBC too.

MySQL defines various [numeric types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html) and you're probably using [`FLOAT`, `DOUBLE` or `DECIMAL(n, m)`, `NUMERIC(n, m)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) which store floating-point numbers.

You need to use `INTEGER` for `year` and `VARCHAR` for `direct_phone`.

Comment: while desc suppliers I get this  direct_phone  | varchar(255) . So this is already in varchar

Comment: Then you need to see if the web controllers don't attempt to convert a `double` to a `String`. Check the web layer converters.

Comment: Then, you need to debug it step-by-step and see where it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

First, it shouldn't be saving a string as an exponential in DB. Is the table column inside DB is varchar(10)?
Second, if you need to convert those strings to what you want, you can do this:

To remove the dot:

```
direct_phone = direct_phone.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```

To remove the 'E':

```
direct_phone = direct_phone.replaceAll("[E]","")
```

Comment: what are you talking about .

Comment: Did you know anything about Spring Data JPA

Comment: @abhaygarg12493 Yes.